# Extract Name from a Data String

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a unstructured data in A1 and want to extract Name from that string can somebody suggest a excel formula for the same

[image]

Comment: In row 4 do you want only Vishal? Or Vishal Builder?

Comment: Only vishal ...but if vishal Builder is also extracted I can delete the same from result afterwards as word Builder will not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER((FIND("(",C5))),MID(C5,(FIND("(",C5)+1),(FIND(" ",C5,(FIND(" ",C5,(FIND("(",C5))))+1))-FIND("(",C5)-1),LEFT(C5,(FIND(" ",C5,(FIND(" ",C5))+1)-1)))
```

This code will check the text for a "(". If the text contain one, then gives back the first two "word" after it. If not, then gives you the first 2 word of the text.

(In row #4 you will need to handle the result manually.)

To handle the one word after the "(" need to modify it above formul for something like this :

```
=IF(ISNUMBER((FIND("(",C7))),(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",C7,FIND(" ",C7,FIND("(",C7))+1)),MID(C7,(FIND("(",C7)+1),(FIND(" ",C7,(FIND(" ",C7,(FIND("(",C7))))+1))-FIND("(",C7)-1),MID(C7,FIND("(",C7)+1,(FIND(" ",C7,FIND("(",C7))-FIND("(",C7))-1))),LEFT(C7,(FIND(" ",C7,(FIND(" ",C7))+1)-1)))
```

Comment: it works well if there are two example (Vishal Ahuja XXXXXXXXXX) but gives error if it has only (Vishal XXXXXXXXX)  .Can u please suggest what to edit in above ? if the name is only single and not double

Comment: It gives error because can find the second space in the text. Need to use an other IF validation to find out if there is 1 or 2 spaces after the (.

Comment: can you please tell where to put that in the above formula ..?? (-:

Comment: Happy to help, please accept as an answer if its ok.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this with just formula? Or can you accept VBA too?
For using VBA:
This would be easy if you could set all the entries to have the name following an (.

You could then search for the ( in the string, take everything after it till you get a 2nd space, or a different character that's not a letter.

Comment: Can try with VBA ..(not an expert in that)  so formula is preferred